# Is there a word in English that describes being homesick towards a time that you haven't lived in?

Tags: word-request

As the title says.

Looking for a word that would explain a person yearning to a time that person hasn't lived in?

For example somebody born in  the 90's saying he wishes he was born during the Wild-West.

I know such word exists in German, but I can't find it anymore, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

Comment: Not an established one, but see this: http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/post/105778238455/anemoia-n-nostalgia-for-a-time-youve-never

Comment: Is the German word *Sehnsucht* ?

Comment: Very similar question on EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50144/is-there-a-term-that-defines-nostalgia-for-something-youve-never-experienced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a word for this in standard English.

"Nostalgia" can be used.  This is more often a longing to return to a past times that have been experienced, but it is sometimes used, perhaps with an adjective:

> This does not lead to a pseudo-romantic nostalgia for the 18th century
>
> Steampunk is nostalgia for a past that never was. (BBC)

The very particular meaning seems not to exist in English, but that doesn't stop people from inventing new words.  On a blog [Dictionary of Obscure Sorrows](http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/post/105778238455/anemoia-n-nostalgia-for-a-time-youve-never) the word "anemoia" is proposed for "nostalgia for a time you've never experienced". But be aware that this word has almost no real use, and won't be found in regular dictionaries.

You may be best using a more general word, like "yearning".

> He yearns to be a cowboy in the Wild West.